# Automatically generate ZSH/Bash completion files

Tags: bash, zsh, autocomplete

Does a tool exist that will automatically generate completion files for both bash and zsh?

I'd like to be able to specify one source of truth for my completions instead of maintaining a separate completion file for bash and zsh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complete short and long options and file names, make sure that the program generates a usage description with `--help` in the same format as GNU tools. Then set it up for completion with:

- `complete -F _longopt myprogram` in bash
- `compdef _gnu_generic myprogram` in zsh

If you want something more powerful, define bash completions and use zsh's bash compatibility mode. Users must call [`bashcompinit`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-bashcompinit) in their `.zshrc`, then they can call `complete -F _myprogram_bash_complete myprogram` in zsh as well as bash. Zsh only emulates a subset of bash, so test your completion function to ensure that it doesn't require features that zsh doesn't emulate.